# How can I access the machine's date format and not the browser's?

Tags: javascript, time, browser, momentjs, date-formatting

I am trying to display a timestamp in the format of the OS itself (unrelated to the browser's settings), using momentJS.

I tried `moment(ts).toDate().toLocaleDateString()` ,
and passing `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().locale` as as parameter.

Is it possible? Can a browser even access OS time settings?

Comment: AFAIK, you can not read it.

Comment: *"in the format of the OS itself"* there's no such thing as a format "of the OS". What do you mean by that? Are you talking about localization?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I mean the date format in which the current date is displayed.
For example: In windows it can be found in the task area and lock screens.

Comment: Okay, that's something that I would really be surprised if you were able to read. So the answer to your question is most probably no.